# How to read all of the text on a line starting on that line?

Tags: c++, input

I am trying to read someone's full name in C++, and obviously that would have spaces (like "John Doe"). The easiest way I can do this (since `cin` by default breaks at whitespace) is with `getline(cin, str)` where "str" is the variable.

However, when doing this, it starts reading text on the next line. Instead of this:

> Please enter your full name > John Doe

You get

> Please enter your full name >
>
> John Doe

Here's the code that produces the result:

```
string fullName;
cout << "Please enter your full name >";
getline(cin, fullName);
```

Is there any way I can read the full line and still keep it on the same line?

Comment: The trick is to avoid emitting the linefeed when printing the prompt. It has nothing to do with the getline call. Please show your code that makes the prompt.

Comment: Can you show the code that causes that effect? I am not sure what you are saying.

Comment: "_However, when doing this, it starts reading text on the next line._" Makes little sense. Please provide [mcve], that illustrates the problem.

Comment: Unless you press return before typing in a name I don't see anything in that code that will move what you type onto the next line. I am still not sure what is supposed to be happening here tbh.

Comment: Given the code sample, I fail to reproduce the output you claim to be receiving. Are you certain, that this is the code, that you are trying to reproduce the issue with?

Comment: Unable to reproduce on Linux.

Comment: "*since `cin` by default breaks at whitespace*" - it is not `cin` itself that does that, it is `operator>>` instead that does.

Answer (score 0):

Without a Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example, it is difficult to diagnose the issue you're having. However, I am able to produce code that reads a line of input from the user without breaking the previous "Enter your name>" line:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string str;
    std::cout << "Please enter your full name > ";
    std::getline(std::cin, str);
    std::cout << "Hello " << str << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

If you've gotten into the habit of appending all `std::cout` lines with `std::endl`, you may have neglected to omit it that time.